# C++ Pointer member function with templates assignment with a member function of another class

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

```
class IShaderParam{
 public:
 std::string name_value;
};

template<class TParam>
class TShaderParam:public IShaderParam{

public:
 void (TShaderParam::*send_to_shader)( const TParam&,const std::string&);
 TShaderParam():send_to_shader(NULL){}
 TParam value;
 void up_to_shader();
};
typedef TShaderParam<float> FloatShaderParam;
typedef TShaderParam<D3DXVECTOR3> Vec3ShaderParam;
```

In another class, I have a vector of IShaderParams* and functions that i want to send to "send_to_shader". I'm trying assign the reference of these functions like this:

```
Vec3ShaderParam *_param = new Vec3ShaderParam;
_param->send_to_shader = &TShader::setVector3;
```

This is the function:

```
void TShader::setVector3(const D3DXVECTOR3 &vec, const std::string &name){

 //...
}
```

And this is the class with IshaderParams*:

```
class TShader{

 std::vector<IShaderParam*> params;

public:
 Shader effect;
 std::string technique_name;

 TShader(std::string& afilename):effect(NULL){};
 ~TShader();
 void setVector3(const D3DXVECTOR3 &vec, const std::string &name);
```

When I compile the project with Visual Studio C++ Express 2008 I recieve this error:

> Error 2 error C2440: '=' :can't make
>   the conversion 'void (__thiscall
>   TShader::* )(const D3DXVECTOR3 &,const
>   std::string &)' a 'void (__thiscall
>   TShaderParam::* )(const TParam
>   &,const std::string &)'
>   c:\users\isagoras\documents\mcv\afoc\shader.cpp
>   127

Can I do the assignment? No? I don't know how :-S
Yes, I know that I can achieve the same objective with other techniques, but I want to know how can I do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `TShader::send_to_shader` is a c-style function pointer?

Member functions [cannot](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/09/49028.aspx) be used as function pointer callbacks - they require a `this` parameter.

Static member functions and global functions can be used as function pointers.

So you can either

1. pass the `this` manually as a parameter to a static function callback, which in turn invokes the member function on the appropriate instance
2. use an interface instead of a function
3. use a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B)

All three require slight architectural changes.

Comment: C++0x will allow casts from free function pointer to PTMF, I suppose requiring generation of a functor. But I don't think that's the problem his error message indicates.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are trying to use incompatible pointers.  `setVector3` is a `TShader` method but `send_to_shader` wants a `TShaderParam` method.

Not knowing exactly what you want, you can get your example to compile by changing this:

```
void (TShaderParam::*send_to_shader)( const TParam&,const std::string&);
```

to this:

```
void (TShader::*send_to_shader)( const TParam&,const std::string&);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to member functions are a bit rigid. It would help if you showed us the line of code that generates the error, but just looking at it,

> `Error 2 error C2440: '=' :can't make
>   the conversion 'void (__thiscall
>   TShader::* )(const D3DXVECTOR3 &,const
>   std::string &)' a 'void (__thiscall
>   TShaderParam::* )(const TParam &,const
>   std::string &)'
>   c:\users\isagoras\documents\mcv\afoc\shader.cpp
>   127`

So you've passed a `void (TShader::* )(const D3DXVECTOR3 &,const std::string &)` but someone expects a `void (TShaderParam::* )(const TParam &,const std::string &)`.

You need to reimplement `setVector3` as a method of a type derived from `TShaderParam` and extract your `D3DXVECTOR3 &` from the first argument, which must be a `TParam`. (But if it's just passing back your own value, you can `static_cast` it to your own type derived from `TParam`.)

Hope this helps!